# How can we create Target table in informatica without using SQL

Tags: informatica

I want create a target table with the help of informatica without creating table in SQL.

Comment: could you pls elaborate your question? You can not create a table without using `create table` statement.

Comment: Informatica does not create tables - it's just using them.